# Angular 2 ng-class depending on function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Im trying to change the class of some elements based on an array. 
I have declared a function to return a boolean and say if the string(state/class) is contained in the array.
I have call it `isState(st: string) {return (this.ArrayWithClasses.indexOf(st) > 0)}`

And then I do

```
[ngClass]="{'class-I-Want-To-Activate': isState('evaluating-this-state') }"
```

But it is´t working. You see my mistake? A best solution?

Edit: It is working if I use just a boolean to toggle the class. So I consider if function is what is wrong...

Comment: update your post with the method and the html markup

Comment: just change like this.ArrayWithClasses.indexOf(st) > -1, index value always start from 0. If not exists it will return -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't check if `indexOf()` value is `> 0`, because, if that string is located on the first place in array, you will get 0.

```
isState(st: string) {
    let temp = this.ArrayWithClasses.indexOf(st);
    if(temp != -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

If searched string is not located in the array , you will get `-1` value for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below

```
isState(st: string) {
    let temp=this.ArrayWithClasses.indexOf(st)
    if(temp)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```